# Posting to blogger via idHTTP

Tags: post, c++builder, indy, blogger, idhttp

I'm trying to post to Blogger using idHTTP component, however, I'm getting "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request" error.

First, I get the Auth code, which works perfectly with by using code below:

```
TStringList *request = new TStringList;
TStringList *response = new TStringList();

IdHTTP2->Request->Connection = "Keep-Alive";
IdHTTP2->Request->ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1->SSLOptions->Method = sslvSSLv23;

request->Clear();
request->Values["accountType"] = "GOOGLE";
request->Values["Email"]       = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
request->Values["Passwd"]      = "yyyyyyy";
request->Values["source"]      = "test-test";
request->Values["service"]     = "blogger";

response->Text = IdHTTP2->Post("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin", request);
auth = response->Values["Auth"];  //working perfectly
```

Then, I get the blogID and finally I try to post an entry to Blogger using code below, but at this moment I get "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request" error.

```
request->Clear();
request->Text = Memo3->Lines->Text;  //put entry into request var

IdHTTP2->Request->CustomHeaders->Clear();
IdHTTP2->Request->CustomHeaders->Add("GData-Version=2.0");
IdHTTP2->Request->CustomHeaders->Add("Authorization: GoogleLogin auth="+auth);
IdHTTP2->Request->ContentType = "application/atom+xml";

response->Text = IdHTTP2->Post("https://www.blogger.com/feeds/" + blogID + "/posts/default", request); // I got "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request" error right here.
```

This is the entry I'm trying to post:

```
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>
  <title type='text'>Marriage!</title>
  <content type='xhtml'>
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <p>Mr. Darcy has <em>proposed marriage</em> to me!</p>
      <p>He is the last man on earth I would ever desire to marry.</p>
      <p>Whatever shall I do?</p>
    </div>
  </content>
  <category scheme="http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#" term="marriage" />
  <category scheme="http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#" term="Mr. Darcy" />
</entry>
```

I have looked for a right way of posting it with idHTTP but I found nothing.. :(

**Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?**

BTW, I'm using CodeGear Delphi/C++Builder 2009 and Indy's version is 10.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Not seeing a problem at first glance, you might try to make sure you've got not extra spaces in the Auth token. I suffered from 400s for a long time until I realize I was picking up an extra space at the end of the Auth token in the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how  to get it working.

I removed line

```
 IdHTTP2->Request->CustomHeaders->Add("GData-Version=2.0");
```

Then I replaced

```
 IdHTTP2->Request->CustomHeaders->Add("Authorization: GoogleLogin auth="+auth);
```

by

```
 IdHTTP2->Request->CustomHeaders->Values["Authorization"] = "GoogleLogin auth="+auth;
```

From: https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=252770